# How do I use an external API with ruby middleman static site generator?

Tags: ruby, middleman, static-site

I've been googling this for a while but it seems nobody has done it or nobody does it in a static site generator. I'm trying to integrate a weather API (json) to make a weather widget in my middleman site. Could anyone point me to the correct direction like where do I put the function calls, how do I manage my functions, how to throttle the frequency of API calls to a specific time per minute?

Comment: it will have to be client-side only because by definition, static sites don't run server-side code on a per-request basis. In other words, look for some javascript library

Comment: yeah, right, what a dumbass I am, thanks! @max

Comment: Please answer so I can mark as accepted